# Android - RecyclerView with one layout, multiple setVisibility

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-view, visibility

I have a basically all in one layout which has everything needed for my app's main feed. All variable items (images, video thumbnails.. Etc.) are set to `GONE` at first and set to `VISIBLE` when it is needed.

The problem is sometimes, might be due to `RecyclerView`'s recycling behavior, the item which is supposedto be `GONE` is `VISIBLE` in the wrong places.

Example :

> Item no 1 contains Text
>
> Item no 2 contains Image
>
> Item no 3 contains Image

I keep scrolling down to item no x, then scroll back up and here's what I get :

> Item no 1 contains Image from item no x, sometimes item no 3
>
> Item no 2 contains Image
>
> Item no 3 contains Image

I'm using a custom ViewHolder which `extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder`.
The purpose of the `CustomViewHolder` is for layout declaration and initialization.

```
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    View viewDimmer;
    RelativeLayout postListWrapper;

    ...

    public ObjectViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.post_inscroll_progressBar);
        viewDimmer = (View)v.findViewById(R.id.post_inscroll_viewDimmer);
        postListWrapper = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.post_inscroll_postListWrapper);
    }
```

An example of how I load the image :

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(youtubeThumbnailUrl)
    .fit()
    .centerCrop()
    .into(
        ((ObjectViewHolder) holder).userPostYoutubeImage
    );
```

I've set each visibility to `GONE` if no url is obtained from the server

```
((ObjectViewHolder) holder).userPostImageWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
((ObjectViewHolder) holder).userPostYoutubeImageWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But somehow the image is still reused on the previous items (yes, not only Item no 1). Sometimes image are also in the wrong `ImageView`. Image D is supposed to be in `ImageView` D, but it's in `ImageView` A instead.

Any guide for setting `RecyclerView` up and going nicely?

If I miss anything, or need to supply more code, please do inform me :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the `else` condition too. Like the example below.

```
// if no url is found from server
if(url == null){
  ((ObjectViewHolder) holder).userPostImageWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  ((ObjectViewHolder) holder).userPostYoutubeImageWrapper.setVisibility(View.GONE);

} else {
  // Some url has found 
  ((ObjectViewHolder) holder).userPostImageWrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  ((ObjectViewHolder) holder).userPostYoutubeImageWrapper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Do this for each of the items you've got there as the list item in case of you're setting their visibilities in runtime.

Comment: It might be worth saying why this is important. The reason being that Holders are reused.

Comment: I just got mind slapped. Thanks Reaz for telling me to use else and thanks @Knossos for telling me that the Holders are reused! So the visibility inside the holder number.. 3 for example, is still there even if we move to holder number 1?

Comment: @Knossos Many thanks for your add. Yes, this is worth sharing.

Comment: @KevinMurvie Correct. It is more efficient to re-use Holders that pop off the end of the RecyclerView than to create new ones. So whenever you set a property in a Holder, it will keep that property for the next time it is used. So it needs to be reset to defaults.

Comment: Alrighty, I'm currently adding `else` wherever a default reset is needed.. Is my approach correct though? As in using a single layout only..

Comment: Yes. You can proceed with what you're doing now. Should work fine

Comment: I realized that I've actually have `else` statement in the other 2 `ImageView`s, but not in the first 2 `ImageView`s, lol. Talk about human error

Answer (score 0):

All your `if` conditions in `onBindViewHolder()` must have an `else` block too.

Don't leave any `if` condition without `else`. You can provide a default behaviour in the `else` block when `if` condition becomes `false`.