# Using Switch in RecyclerView srcoll

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have use the `Switch` in the `RecyclerView`. It have facing the issue of recycling behaviour. When I switch on the 1st position ,it automatically on the switch at 10 postion ... I think it due to reuse of the view. How to fix it. find the screenshot:
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ms2jf9e28fyc7u/error.png?dl=0

```
    private void setAdapter(ArrayList data) {

            ManageCategoryAdapter adapter = new ManageCategoryAdapter(data);
            adapter.SetOnItemClickListener(listClick);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
     public class ManageCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ManageCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    private ArrayList<String> catData=new ArrayList<>();
    private OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;


    public ManageCategoryAdapter(ArrayList<String> listadap) {
        catData=listadap;
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$"+"adapterclass");

    }


    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_list, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }


    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.category.setText(catData.get(position));


    }


    public int getItemCount() {

        return catData.size();
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public TextView category;
        public Switch switchClick;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            category=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_text);
            switchClick=(Switch)itemView.findViewById(R.id.switch_btn);
            switchClick.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getPosition());
            }

        }
    }
    public void myNotifyDataSetChanged(ArrayList list)
    {
        System.out.println("$$$notify");
        catData.addAll(list);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void SetOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }
}
```

This how I set the adapter class

Comment: please post your `ManageCategoryAdapter`

Comment: find the adapter class

Comment: also post the code in `onItemClick` callback function

Comment: You have to maintain state for every switch button

Comment: how to manage that one

Comment: You are correct. It is because of recycling behavior. you can keep a HashSet for storing positions for which switch is on and then in your onBindViewHolder() you can check if position is present in your hashset then call setChecked(true) for the switch otherwise call setChecked(false) for the switch. Note that you will have to set it to true or false always based on position. Also add or remove position from hashset based on your switch getting checked or unchecked. You already have the instance of switch in your view holder so use that in onBindViewHolder(). Hope that will help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this in the adapter:

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Comment: It works, but there is one question. I believe that it is not sufficient at all, what is the best choice? for example, I have 100 items and with this approach, I am crating literally 100 item

Comment: @YasinHajilou now I could recomend to start using ListAdapter. It's a really good update and option besides RecyclerView. You could check this article for more information: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/adapting-to-listadapter-341da4218f5b

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem with `RecyclerView` and there are lots of answers there in Stackoverflow.

You already have understood your problem i.e. reusing the views. So you might take a look at these answers to get a better idea about how you can overcome it.

- [Put an else condition everywhere you need to update a view of a list
  item dynamically.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36327143/3145960)
- Using another list to keep track of the list items in which the
  `Switch` is enabled or disabled. You can see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36401379/3145960).

These will do the trick for you I hope.