# Checkbox selection issue in listView in android

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I am newbie to android and working on a listView which is having checkboxes in items,When i check any item other item also cehcked automaticaly,Can any one help me how to solve it my adapter is as below,

```
public class ServiceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contArray;
    ArrayList<Boolean> checked;


    private Context mContext;
    String resnID, reson;
    Intent i;

    public ServiceAdapter(Context paramContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contList) {
        this.mContext = paramContext;
        this.contArray = contList;
        checked = new ArrayList<>();

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.contArray.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
        return Integer.valueOf(paramInt);
    }

    public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;
    }

    public View getView(final int paramInt, View paramView,
            ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService("layout_inflater");
        Viewholder localViewholder = null;
        Const.selectedIDs.clear();
        if (paramView == null) {
            paramView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.raw_single_contact, paramViewGroup, false);
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();

            localViewholder.tv_name = ((TextView) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_name));
            localViewholder.chk_id = ((CheckBox) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.chk_id));

            paramView.setTag(localViewholder);
            paramView.setTag(R.id.chk_id, localViewholder.chk_id );

        } else {

            localViewholder = (Viewholder) paramView.getTag();
        }
        localViewholder.tv_name.setText(contArray.get(paramInt).get("serviceText"));

        localViewholder.chk_id.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                try {


                    if (isChecked) {
                        Const.selectedIDs.add(contArray.get(paramInt));
                        Const.serviceArrayList.get(paramInt).put("flag", "1");
                    } else {
                        Const.selectedIDs.remove(contArray.get(paramInt));
                        Const.serviceArrayList.get(paramInt).put("flag", "0");
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });


    return paramView;

    }

    static class Viewholder {


    TextView tv_name;
    CheckBox chk_id;


    }



}
```

Comment: Refer this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36807029/using-switch-in-recyclerview-srcoll/36807323#36807323

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, this will help you,

```
   @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  ViewHolder holder = null;
  Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

  if (convertView == null) {
  LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
  Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

  holder = new ViewHolder();
  holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
  holder.name = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
  convertView.setTag(holder);

  holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {  
  public void onClick(View v) {  
  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v ;  
  Country country = (Country) cb.getTag();  
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
   "Clicked on Checkbox: " + cb.getText() +
   " is " + cb.isChecked(), 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  country.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
 }  
});  
} 
  else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
 }

  Country country = countryList.get(position);
  holder.code.setText(" (" +  country.getCode() + ")");
  holder.name.setText(country.getName());
  holder.name.setChecked(country.isSelected());
  holder.name.setTag(country);

  return convertView;

  }

 }


private void checkButtonClick() {


Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findSelected);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
responseText.append("The following were selected...\n");

ArrayList<Country> countryList = dataAdapter.countryList;
for(int i=0;i<countryList.size();i++){
 Country country = countryList.get(i);
 if(country.isSelected()){
  responseText.append("\n" + country.getName());
 }
}

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
  responseText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go read comments which i added.

```
  public class ServiceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contArray;
        ArrayList<Boolean> checked;

        private Context mContext;
        String resnID, reson;
        Intent i;

        public ServiceAdapter(Context paramContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contList) {
            this.mContext = paramContext;
            this.contArray = contList;
            //update code there make list of same size as contList
            checked = new ArrayList<>(contList.size());
            //On start all are unchecked
            Collections.fill(checked, Boolean.FALSE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return this.contArray.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
            return Integer.valueOf(paramInt);
        }

        public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
            return paramInt;
        }

        public View getView(final int paramInt, View paramView,
                            ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
            LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                    .getSystemService("layout_inflater");
            Viewholder localViewholder = null;
            Const.selectedIDs.clear();
            if (paramView == null) {
                paramView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.raw_single_contact, paramViewGroup, false);
                localViewholder = new Viewholder();

                localViewholder.tv_name = ((TextView) paramView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_name));
                localViewholder.chk_id = ((CheckBox) paramView
                        .findViewById(R.id.chk_id));

                paramView.setTag(localViewholder);
                // dont need below line try without below line if it works comment it otherwise let it stay there.
                paramView.setTag(R.id.chk_id, localViewholder.chk_id);

            } else {
                localViewholder = (Viewholder) paramView.getTag();
            }

            localViewholder.tv_name.setText(contArray.get(paramInt).get("serviceText"));
            localViewholder.chk_id.setChecked(checked.get(paramInt));
            localViewholder.chk_id.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    try {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            checked.set(paramInt, true);
                            Const.selectedIDs.add(contArray.get(paramInt));
                            Const.serviceArrayList.get(paramInt).put("flag", "1");
                        } else {
                            checked.set(paramInt, false);
                            Const.selectedIDs.remove(contArray.get(paramInt));
                            Const.serviceArrayList.get(paramInt).put("flag", "0");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            return paramView;
        }

        public class Viewholder {
            TextView tv_name;
            CheckBox chk_id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi..Ii am checking it ,bro

Comment: @sulphuricAcid  hope it will fix your issue.

Comment: I am getting arrayIndexoutofbounds exception..in your code.

Comment: localViewholder.chk_id.setChecked(checked.get(paramInt)); at this line