# Android RecyclerView Duplicate Item When Scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, move

I have a problem in `RecyclerView`. When I move item in RV and then scroll, saw some items has duplicated.

Comment: add your code please

Comment: See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36327143/3145960

Comment: @mehrdadkhosravi now code added.

Comment: @ReazMurshed Your answer did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RecyclerView` will recycle the view.When you delete data,call `notifyItemChanged(pos)`or `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

Answer (score 61):

I know its late but hope it will help someone. Override these two methods in your adapter.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position;
}
```

Comment: To give some explanation: getItemViewType's default implementation returns 0, making the assumption of a single view type for the adapter. Overriding it lets the adapter know that that there are multiple view types and to adjust accordingly.

Comment: this doesn't help fixing the duplicate items

Answer (score 8):

I think I'm late in here but anyway I'll suggest a way that worked good for me, maybe someone still facing problems with this..
So, I added my recyclerview inside a nestedScrollView then disabled nested scrolling for my recyclerview.

Using this method the scrolling will be detected by the nestedScrollView, and the recyclerview stopped duplicating items while scrolling.

**That's my xml code:**

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you. Additionally, I did not add "nestedScrollingEnabled= false" but it worked anyway.

Comment: Great to hear that @PinkRabbits but keep in mind that this will stop the main functioning of recyclerview which is recycling items.

Comment: you saved my day...I spent around 5-6 hours searching for this issue but nothing worked until your solution!! thank you very much....

Answer (score 0):

It is your `notifyDataSetChanged()` that is the issue.

Check that you used it properly.

That is:

```
private void parseJsonFeed(JSONArray response) {

for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++)
        try {
            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
            MyData myData = new MyData();
            myData.setContent_title(obj.getString("content_title"));
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ...
            // adding content to array
            homeList.add(myData);
              } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
   //this must always be called else the recycler would not understand when to stop or start working.
    recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```