# Issue: Two checkbox are checked at a time while select any checkbox in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

Now I am using RecyclerView with CheckBox. My Goal is get selected Checkbox list. Here My Problem is while I try to select any one Checkbox means it select two Checkbox at the same time. For example I am select in 0th position Checkbox but It automatically select 0th and 13th Both position Checkbox are getting selected.

> There is no duplicate item adding while scrolling, Please understand clearly..

Here I have to attached my RecyclerView Adapter Class. Please any one help me..

Thanks in Advance.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ModuleViewModel> items =  new ArrayList<>();
    private OnItemCheckListener onItemClick;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_modules_list, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ModuleViewModel currentItem = items.get(position);
        holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder.checkbox.setChecked(
                            ! holder.checkbox.isChecked());
                    if ( holder.checkbox.isChecked()) {
                        onItemClick.onItemChecked(currentItem);
                    } else {
                        onItemClick.onItemUnchecked(currentItem);
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public interface OnItemCheckListener {
        void onItemChecked(ModuleViewModel item);
        void onItemUnchecked(ModuleViewModel item);
    }

    public MyAdapter (Context context,ArrayList<ModuleViewModel> items, @NonNull OnItemCheckListener onItemCheckListener) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.items = items;
        this.onItemClick = onItemCheckListener;
    }


    static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkbox;
        View itemView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.itemView = itemView;
            checkbox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.uiCkbModule);
            checkbox.setClickable(false);

        }

        public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        }
    }
}
```

This is My Adapter calling Code

```
mModuleListAdapter = new ModuleListAdapter(mContext, mModuleListModel, this);
 mRvModuleView.setAdapter(mModuleListAdapter);
```

Comment: use Boolean field in model class and use that field for selection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android RecyclerView Duplicate Item When Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506978/android-recyclerview-duplicate-item-when-scrolling)

Comment: @user8, You guys are understand or not?... any where I am say **Duplicate Item When Scrolling**? then how you mark as duplicate?

Comment: I don't know the reason for why You guys are giving down vote for this.. any one can tell the reason. If you know the Solution give a solution. Please...

Answer (score 2):

Hello @Raja this is due to recyclerview behaviour. I have faced same issue so for solution I store the checkbox status in my model

> public boolean status = false;

by default 
than onclicklistner update the status in the list view this will sove your issue.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Student student = items.get(position);
    holder.checkbox.setText(student.name + " :: " + student.department);
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(student.status);
    holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.checkbox.isChecked()) {
                onItemClick.onItemChecked(student);
            } else {
                onItemClick.onItemUnchecked(student);
            }
            student.status = holder.checkbox.isChecked();
            items.remove(position);
            items.add(position, student);
        }
    });
}
```

than its perfectly working for me..

Answer (score 1):

Could you please modify the following function, I believe ModelViewModel object will have some boolean variable to hold the state of check box.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final ModuleViewModel currentItem = items.get(position);
        holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.checkbox.setChecked(! holder.checkbox.isChecked());
                if ( holder.checkbox.isChecked()) {
                    onItemClick.onItemChecked(currentItem);
                } else {
                    onItemClick.onItemUnchecked(currentItem);
                }
            }
        });

        if(!currentItem.isChecked) {
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
        }else {
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This mostly happens because recyclerview recycles/reuses already created item views to reduce resource consumption.

There can be two approaches to handle this:

1. Add a boolean variable ***isChecked*** in your ***ModuleViewModel*** model class
   and set it true/false for every list item. In this approach, the value of checked would be save for every model class in the class itself.
2. Create an arraylist of booleans ***isChecked*** of same size of the ***items***. Each element of ***isChecked*** arraylist will correspond to each item of the recyclerview list. You can then refer to the value of ***isChecked*** at that position to setChecked(true/false) your checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this take  one `boolean` in your model like this `isChecked` and create getter and setter method for `boolean` variable

```
holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                items.get(position).isChecked=isChecked;
            } else {    
                items.get(position).isChecked=isChecked;
            }

        }
    });
```

than try this

```
holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    if ( items.get(position).isChecked())) {
                        onItemClick.onItemChecked(currentItem);
                    } else {
                        onItemClick.onItemUnchecked(currentItem);
                    }
            }
        });
```

Comment: `this is not a solution Boss` can you explain why

Comment: Now i dont need `holder.setOnClickListener` this part of code. without any listeners and click event only I need.

Comment: than what about this condition `holder.checkbox.setChecked(
                            ! holder.checkbox.isChecked());` can explain more what you want to achieve

Comment: Boss, That and all not a problem. Please understand. Who one use Boolean in unwanted place.. Its not good programming.