# Recycleview Scrolling Issue Add Element arraylist again and again scroll down and up

Tags: android

i have Problem when come screen some item is switch on add in one arraylist and scroll down then up again this value add in array list  again issue pls as fast solution.

```
public class NeedSizeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NeedSizeAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        private List<SizeModel> sizeModelList;


        public NeedSizeAdapter(List<SizeModel> numbers) {
            this.sizeModelList = new ArrayList<>(numbers);
            selecteSizeList = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_rv_notificationsetting, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            holder.bindData(sizeModelList.get(position));

            //in some cases, it will prevent unwanted situations
            holder.mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

            //if true, your checkbox will be selected, else unselected


        holder.mSwitch.setChecked(sizeModelList.get(position).isSelected());
                if (sizeModelList.get(position).isSelected()) {
                    selecteSizeList.add(sizeModelList.get(position).getSizeId());
                    Log.d("selectedSize", sizeModelList.get(position).getSizeId());
                }
                holder.mSwitch.setTag(sizeModelList.get(position));

                holder.mSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        Switch cb = (Switch) buttonView;
                        SizeModel contact = (SizeModel) cb.getTag();

                        contact.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
                        sizeModelList.get(position).setSelected(cb.isChecked());
    //                    sizeModelList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).setSelected(isChecked);
                        if (isChecked) {
                            selecteSizeList.add(sizeModelList.get(position).getSizeId());
                        } else {
                            selecteSizeList.remove(sizeModelList.get(position).getSizeId());
                        }


                    }
                });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return sizeModelList.size();
        }
```

Comment: How do you fill your adapter? and if you have scrollListener please post it too.

Comment: take a global  boolean value and store the status of isSelected then check the condition (`if (sizeModelList.get(position).isSelected() && isTrue) {
`) along with boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override methods getItemId and getItemViewType

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position;
}
```

This is answered here. 
See the original answer here :
[Android RecyclerView Duplicate Item When Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506978/android-recyclerview-duplicate-item-when-scrolling)

Comment: but using recycleview two method not available

Answer (score 0):

I think this is

```
if (sizeModelList.get(position).isSelected()) {
                selecteSizeList.add(sizeModelList.get(position).getSizeId());
                Log.d("selectedSize", sizeModelList.get(position).getSizeId());
            }
```

superfluous .because you have add `setOnCheckedChangeListener` so you can delete up